# CSS working for certain browsers and not others(Website not working on Firefox and chrome )

Tags: html, css

I am having issues with the website I am currently working on.Basically this website does not work with all the browsers.I works for example with Firefox 13.0 but not with the FF7.0 and work with Chrome 18.0 but not with an older versions.Same scenario with IE 9.0 but not on IE 6.0.Here is the website:http://www.microboticsinc.com/Test/home.html. 
At the moment it is working on 3 machines in the company only. 
So to resume I only have 2 main issues at the moment.
1-Resizing: when I zoom in/out.It basically puts the background images all over the place.May be I need to add a specification on the my CSS code.
2-The fact that it is not all browsers compatible.

Here is my background mcb.css:

```css
.outerDiv {    
    border:solid 3px transparent;
    width:1070px;
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    color:black;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.nestedDivTL {
    background-color:transparent;
    width: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 165px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 596px;
}

.nestedDivTR {
     background-color:transparent;
     position:absolute;
     top:50px;
     right:400px;
}

.nestedDivBL {
     background-color:transparent;
     width:400px;
     height:300px; 
     position:absolute;
     top:200px;
     right:25px;
}

.nestedDivBR {
     background-color:transparent;
     width:400px;
     position:absolute;
     top:200px;
     right:450px;
}

.nestedDivBG {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:Auto;
    height:Auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.nestedDivSC {
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 176px;
    left: 202px;
}

.nestedDivnf {
    background-color:transparent;       
    position:absolute;
    top:420px;
    left:15px;
    width: 160px;
    height:568px;
    bottom: 12px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

a:hover{text-decoration: underline; color:green} 

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.transparent {
    /* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */        
    width: 100%; 
    /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
    /* ...but not required as filter works too */
    /* should come BEFORE filter */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
    /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    /* Modern!
    /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
    /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
    opacity: 0.5;
}    


body {
    background-image: url("Resources/Web Page Parts/Misc/Map.gif"); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat center center-fixed;
}

html { 
    background:transparent url("Resources/Web Page Parts/Back Drops/carb.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    display: block;                       
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tested the css with a validator on w3c.org and solved the errors they showed me.
Can someone please have an idea what I omitted or how to find my error?I am running out of ideas how to fix these issues.

Comment: Could you post the html too? There could be some problems that we will only be able to see when we have both the html and css.

Comment: @Jcubed sorry i figured you can see the source code on the link i sent:http://microboticsinc.com/Test/home.html.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem here lies with this bit:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Here's a chart I found that describes the browser compatability for background cover. It's toward the bottom.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html

Comment: @Scotty.Thank you Scotty for the quick answer.I removed this part also and tried it again.But like I said it worked with a FF13+ and IE9+ and Chrome18+. But not on the older versions.It still did not solve the issue.http://www.microboticsinc.com/Test/home.html

Comment: If you apply the background styling to containing divs, they won't float all around when you mess with the zoom. As you have it now, the background images are independent from the elements they are supposed to be behind, so they are free to float around. So for instance, if you put the map background on the `.nestedDivSC` div, it will always be behind the content. Also, the dark blue background looks as if it was intended to be set to repeat across the screen, instead of being centered.

Comment: @Scotty.Hey Scotty I tried to go with your advice and he worked.But somehow the background image cannot be resized and also on IE it is messed up.The image is cut in half.Than I tried what tahdhaze09 advised to resize background images.But I was not successful.Here is the latest of the website:http://microboticsinc.com/Test/home.html. If someone has an idea what i am doing wrong please.I just spend my whole day on the subject.Thank you guys

Comment: Since your layout appears to be static width, you could resize the images to fit the divs.

Comment: Also, I noticed that your current blue background is over 2000 pixels wide, which makes your page take forever to load. I resized it in GIMP for you, so if you upload this one, and set it to repeat, it will cover the entire screen and take a fraction of the time to load. http://ubuntuone.com/7f4g3fTK0AFArB3b6B7aiu

Comment: It works perfectly now.what I did is resizing the map picture so it can't fit.I did it by adding width and height on the .nestedDivSC.

Comment: Now I have to create a special css for ie because the changes i made are not accepted by IE.Thanks Scotty

Comment: I would probably create a separate stylesheet for IE, then load it with JavaScript or PHP browser detection. It's often difficult to get the desired effects across all browsers with one stylesheet. Although I personally don't write special code for IE, because people have to expect things to look less than perfect in a non-standards compliant browser. That's just me though.

Comment: Hey Scotty,I pretty much fixed what was to fix beside IE which keeps giving me trouble with the background which does not fit probably and think is a stackoverflow issue.but I tried to solve it by creating a Stylesheet for IE but it does not recognize it. I also wanted the website to stretch like this website:http://buellxb.com/ what did I do wrong?Here is the current website:http://www.microboticsinc.com/Test/home2.html .Help please

Comment: I think we're getting in a little too deep here. StackOverflow is for asking a pointed question and getting an appropriate answer, not necessarily advice on redoing an entire layout. Unfortunately, making that layout fluid width is not going to be easy, and will require a lot of recoding. My advice would be to research fluid HTML layouts, then build one yourself using the appropriate methods. If you do it right, there should be no need to use workarounds for older browsers. You might also consider finding a good web design forum where you can open a topic and ask questions as you go.

Comment: Hey Scotty,I have totally redone the whole homepage.here is the link:http://www.microboticsinc.com/Test/WIP/testhome2.html.But I am still wondering why the previous one did not work in IE and it is only the homepage:http://www.microboticsinc.com/Test/home.html which has this problem.The rest of the site works perfectly.Any ideas why it is acting like that?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm using Linux, and thus, don't have IE. Therefore, I can't test your site with it. Congratulations on getting the new one working right though! It looks great.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a background image to cover an element, try this:

```
.bg {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5000;
}
```

This link has code samples and a demo of resizable full background images. You can place this on a div or paragraph, anything.

Code:

```
#img.source-image {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Link:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Comment: :Thank you so much.I did try this path.But it did not quiet work for me.

Comment: Thank you,tahdhaze09.This is a method I will definitely use for future projects.